# Console2 not using PS1 colours

Tags: cygwin, ps1, console2

I am using Cygwin in Console2 with the following PS1

```
export PS1='\[\e]2;\w\a\e[1;32m\e[40m\n\w\n\d - \@ > \[\e[0;00m\]'
```

The prompt has the correct text content, but all the colors are ignored.

```
~/wd
Tue Mar 18 - 01:14 PM >
```

Screenshot showing Console2:

[image: Screenshot showing prompt Console2]

When I use mintty, the colours are perfect.

[image: Screenshot showing prompt in mintty]

TERM is set the same in both Console2 and mintty:

```
Tue Mar 18 - 06:29 PM > env | grep TERM
TERM=cygwin
TERMCAP=SC|screen|VT 100/ANSI X3.64 virtual terminal:\
```

Comment: Looks like non-standard palette in Console2. What are your colors there?

Comment: Colors for Console2 are set up as per: http://www.curlybrace.com/words/2012/02/12/console2-and-cygwin-with-solarized-color-palette/. But note that I see the exact same issue with and without this colour set i.e. even if I reset the colours in console.xml to their default, the same issue occurs.

Comment: Compare your environment in mintty and Console. May be you need to set `TERM` variable for ansi, win32, or anything...

Comment: Updated answer with TERM settings.

Comment: "HOME" and cygwin version?

Comment: Home: `/home/robbram`. Version: `CYGWIN_NT-6.1-WOW64`

Answer (score 0):

You have not show your screenshots. So I'm not sure what do you meaning.

But I believe it is cygwin feature (bug). It thinks that ANSI is not available in Windows terminal (that is true for Console2, but of course not if you are using ANSICON or ConEmu). That means that cygwin process **all** ANSI sequences internally (it does not send them to the terminal). So, if any problems happens, that all is cygwin implementation problems.

Comment: I have added screenshots of the prompt as viewed in mintty (works perfectly) vs Console2 (which is ignoring the colours).

Comment: How do you run bash from Console2?

Comment: How I run bash from Console2: Console2 > Settings > tab > Shell: C:\cygwin\bin\bash.exe --login -i

Comment: Try "sh.exe --login -i", it may be different. Also, you may try ConEmu as terminal. May be it is Console2 issue (not sure).

Comment: Exactly the same result with `C:\cygwin\bin\sh.exe --login -i`